# Шифрование методом AES

Tags: java, android, криптография

Здравствуйте, есть такой вот код, по идее он должен зашифровать слово "hello" и здесь же дешифровать, вывести в  text view, но при запуске приложение вылетает. В чем моя ошибка?

```
 private void main(String[] args)throws LoginException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
       String s = "hello";
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

      //  KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
      //  kgen.init(128);
     //   SecretKey key = kgen.generateKey();
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec("bar12345Bar12345".getBytes(),"AES");

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,key);
        byte[] bytes = cipher.doFinal(s.getBytes());
        for (byte b : bytes){
          //  time.setText(s+" "+ b);

        }
      //  String str = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        Cipher decript = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        decript.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,key);
        byte[] decriptedBytes = decript.doFinal(bytes);
        for (byte b : decriptedBytes){

time.setText((char) b);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ошибка в том, что вы не привели текста ошибки, с которой оно вылетает. Что у вас с паддингом при шифровании, кстати?

Comment: Ошибка указывает на строку где setText  и пишет примерно следующее  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x68

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас `time.setText((char) b)` пытается достать строку из ресурсов по int'овому идентификатору и установить её. В метод нужно передавать строку:

```
time.setText(String.valueOf((char) b));
```